# stripe: throw errnoException(process._errno, 'spawn');

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, stripe-payments

I have a piece of code collecting a user'list: [here is the gist](https://gist.github.com/Abdelkrim/8658078)

When I run my code I receive the following error (my lack of javascript skills is the main issue here)

1. I collect the stripe accounts
2. I set the count to 100
3. I gather the 100 first customers accounts
4. I loop in 3 until all accounts are gathered (if count < size(latest customer' list)

> child_process.js:927
>       throw errnoException(process._errno, 'spawn');
>             ^ Error: spawn EAGAIN
>
> ```
> at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
> at ChildProcess.spawn (child_process.js:927:11)
> at exports.spawn (child_process.js:715:9)
> at Object.exports.execFile (child_process.js:607:15)
> at exports.exec (child_process.js:578:18)
> at Object.Stripe.getClientUserAgent (/myProjectDir/node_modules/stripe/lib/stripe.js:125:5)
> at Object.StripeResource._request (/myProjectDir/node_modules/stripe/lib/StripeResource.js:175:18)
> at Object.list (/myProjectDir/node_modules/stripe/lib/StripeMethod.js:45:10)
> at async.series.customers (/myProjectDir/app/lib/stripeKPIs.js:26:30)
> at /myProjectDir/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:551:21
> ```

## StripeDashboard.js

```
var url = require('url');
var nodedump = require('nodedump').init({ expand: true }).dump;
var stripeKPIs = require('../lib/stripeKPIs.js');
var async = require('async');
module.exports = function (app) {


    app.get('/stripe/dashboard', function (req, res) {


        var parts = url.parse(req.url, true);
        var queryString = parts.query;

        var payingCustomers = -1;
        var apiKey = req.session.user.credentials.access_token;

        console.log('/stripe/dashboard: queryString: ' + JSON.stringify(queryString));
        console.log('/stripe/dashboard: apiKey: ' + apiKey);

        async.waterfall([function (callback) {


            callback(null, stripeKPIs.payingCustomers(apiKey, new Date(2013, 1, 1), new Date(2013, 12, 1)));
        }],
            function (err, aSyncResults) {

                payingCustomers = aSyncResults[0];
                console.log('*********************');
                console.log('callback called! ' + JSON.stringify(payingCustomers));

            });


        res.render('stripe/stripeDashboard.html', {payingCustomers: payingCustomers, session: req.session});

    });
};
```

## StripeKPIs.js

```
var async = require('async');

function StripeException(message) {
    this.message = message;
    this.name = "StripeException";
}


function payingCustomers(apiKey, startDate, endDate, callback) {
    // see https://stripe.com/docs/api/node#list_customers
    // return(how many customers)
    var kontinue = true;
    var result = []; //json containing all customers.data


    var stripe = require("stripe")(apiKey);
    var count = 100;
    var offset = 0;


    while (kontinue) {


        async.series([function (callback) {

            stripe.customers.list({count: count, offset: offset/*, gte: startDate, lte: endDate*/}, function (err, customers) {
                if (err) {
                    kontinue = false;
                    throw new StripeException('stripe.customers.list error: ' + err);
                }
                else {
                    console.log('collectCustomers: offset: ' + offset + ' - customers: ' + JSON.stringify(customers));
                    callback(null, customers);
                }
            });
        }],
            function (err, aSyncResults) {
                console.log('count(' + count + ') - offset(' + offset + ')');
                console.log('inside the callback');
                if (err) {
                    console.errror('async callback error: ' + err);
                    return next(err);
                }
                var customers = aSyncResults[0];

                result = result.concat(customers.data);
                if (customers.data.length < count) {
                    console.log('customers.data.length(' + customers.data.length + ') < count (' + count + ')');
                    kontinue = false;
                }


                offset = result.length;
                console.log('payingCustomers: offset: ' + offset + ' - result: ' + result.length);
                console.log('aSyncResults: offset: ' + offset + ' - result: ' + aSyncResults[0].data.length);
            });
    }
    return(result);
}

module.exports.payingCustomers = payingCustomers;
```

## console.log output

```
Running "jshint:gruntfile" (jshint) task
>> 1 file lint free.

Running "jshint:lib" (jshint) task
>> 16 files lint free.

Running "jshint:test" (jshint) task
>> 1 file lint free.

Running "nodemon:dev" (nodemon) task
[nodemon] v1.0.13
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: app/**/*
[nodemon] starting `node --debug ./server.js dev`
debugger listening on port 5858
connect.multipart() will be removed in connect 3.0
visit https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/wiki/Connect-3.0 for alternatives
connect.limit() will be removed in connect 3.0
'development' === app.get('env')
listening to https://mymachine.local:3001
Connected to mongoose
/stripe/dashboard: queryString: {}
/stripe/dashboard: apiKey: sk_test_1234
startDate(Fri Mar 01 2013) - endDate(Thu Jan 01 2015)
*********************
callback called! undefined


collectCustomers: offset: 0 - customers: {"object":"list","count":14,"url":"/v1/customers","data":[{"object":"customer","created":1333799,"id":"cus_2LeD54sf3k","livemode":false,"description":"My test env","email":"your@email.com","delinquent":false,"metadata":{},"subscription":{"id":"sub_01","plan":{"interval":"year","name":"Standard plan billed yearly","created":13074184,"amount":2000,"currency":"eur","id":"StdYear","object":"plan","livemode":false,"interval_count":1,"trial_period_days":null,"metadata":{}}....]}

count(100) - offset(0)

inside the callback

customers.data.length(14) < count (100)

payingCustomers: offset: 14 - result: 14

aSyncResults: offset: 14 - result: 14
```

Comment: do the console.log produce the expected result ? This might be incorrect: `offset = result.length;` as it would lead you to always get the same 'page' of customers. Try to increment with `offset += result.length;`
Another problem is the loop `while (kontinue)`. Instead, use a recursive function, this might fix your issue. Let me know how it goes

Comment: another question I have is why you are using `async.waterfall` to run only a function and its callback, but I guess you have presented us simplified code here and you run more functions in your production code.

Comment: @mef this isn't a simplified piece of code; I tried many solutions and the async.waterfall was the latest version of my code.

this might be removed if necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I met @Abdelkrim irl and we fixed his problem by replacing the `while(kontinue)` loop by a recursive function.

cf. pattern explained here: http://www.richardrodger.com/2011/04/21/node-js-how-to-write-a-for-loop-with-callbacks/#.UufBCD0o9hE